# coverImage path undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error, backend, multer

while sending POST req. in postman im getting error that coverImage path is undefine "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')",
when i console log the req.files im only getting the avatar obj in array but it should include the coverImage.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYisD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69SRN.png)

here the user.controller.js code

```js
import { asyncHandler } from '../utils/asyncHandler.js';
import { ApiError } from '../utils/ApiError.js';
import { User } from '../models/user.model.js';
import {uploadToCloudinary} from '../utils/cloudinary.js';
import { ApiResponse } from '../utils/ApiResponse.js';

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // get the user data from the request body
    // validate the user data not empty
    // check if the user already exists
    // check for img, and avatar
    // upload to cloudinary, avatar
    // create user object -creat entry in db
    // remove password and token from the object
    // check for user creation
    // return the response

    const {fullName, email, userName, password} = req.body
    console.log(fullName, email, userName, password)

    if(!fullName || !email || !userName || !password){
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Please fill all the fields')
    }

    const existedUser = await User.findOne({
        $or: [
            {email},
            {userName}
        ]
    })

    if(existedUser){
        throw new ApiError(409, 'User already exists')
    }

    console.log(req.files)
    const avatarLocalPath = req.files?.avatar[0]?.path
    const coverImageLocalPath = req.files?.coverImage[0]?.path || "" //Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    if(!avatarLocalPath){
        throw new ApiError(400, 'Please provide an avatar')
    }

    const avatar = await uploadToCloudinary(avatarLocalPath)
    const coverImage = await uploadToCloudinary(coverImageLocalPath)

    if(!avatar){
        throw new ApiError(500, 'Error uploading avatar')
    }

    const user = await User.create({
        fullName,
        email,
        userName: userName.toLowerCase(),
        password,
        avatar: avatar.url,
        coverImage: coverImage?.url || ""
    })
    const createdUser = await User.findById(user._id).select('-password -refreshToken')

    if(!createdUser){
        throw new ApiError(500, 'Something went wrong while registering the user')
    }

    return res.status(201).json(new ApiResponse(201, createdUser, 'User registered successfully'))
    
})

export { registerUser }
```

multer.middleware.js

```js
import multer from "multer"

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./public/temp")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

export const upload = multer({ 
    storage, 
})
```

user.routes.js

```js
import { Router } from "express"; 
import { registerUser } from "../controllers/user.controller.js";
import {upload} from "../middlewares/multer.middleware.js";

const router = Router();

router.route('/register').post(
    upload.fields([
        {name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1},
        {name: 'coverImage', maxCount: 2}
    ]),
    registerUser
    )

export default router;
```

and the cloudinary.js

```
import {v2 as cloudinary} from 'cloudinary'
import fs from 'fs'

// Configure cloudinary
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: process.env.COULDINARY_CLOUD_NAME, 
  api_key: process.env.COULDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.COULDINARY_API_SECRET
});

const uploadToCloudinary = async (localFilePath) => {
    try{
        if(!localFilePath) {
        throw new Error('No file received')
        }
        // Upload file to cloudinary
        const response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(localFilePath, { resource_type: "auto" })

        //file uploaded successfully
        console.log(response.url);
        return response;

    } catch(error) {
        fs.unlinkSync(localFilePath) // Delete the locally saved temp. file if it was not uploaded to cloudinary
        return null;
    }
        
}


export { uploadToCloudinary }
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that **req.files?.coverImage** is a list then just replace it with the below line of code in the existing code file.

```
const coverImageLocalPath = req.files?.coverImage?.[0]?.path || "";
```